# How do I set the spring active profile using consul?

Tags: spring, consul, spring-cloud-consul

I have a consul env:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
blah blah other stuff
```

I've verified that the consul env properties are being read by the spring app (it locates the right property source and I can see that its reading properties in other log messages), however this is also appearing in the log

No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default

Comment: It’s clearly a timing issue. Have you tried using a debugger to walk through the code that spits out the message and the code that reads the property from Consul?

Comment: Log file says the PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration finds the properties file before it tries to set the profile